SQLAlchemy polymorph association
Good night, I would like to ask if it is possible to use an associative table in polymorphism. Let's say this is the case
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import ConcreteBase


class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = "company"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    employees = relationship("Employee")


class Employee(ConcreteBase, Base):
    __tablename__ = "employee"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    company_id = Column(ForeignKey("company.id"))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "employee",
        "concrete": True,
    }


class Manager(Employee):
    __tablename__ = "manager"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    manager_data = Column(String(40))
    company_id = Column(ForeignKey("company.id"))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "manager",
        "concrete": True,
    }


class Engineer(Employee):
    __tablename__ = "engineer"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    engineer_info = Column(String(40))
    company_id = Column(ForeignKey("company.id"))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "engineer",
        "concrete": True,
    }

Can I specify in Company.employees not through company_id, but simply through an associative table? If so, please give me an example of what I should associate the associative table with and how? Sorry in advance for my English. It's not my native language.
